# Failed to open connection

Tags: c#

I have a client/server application under Windows with *crystal report version 13.0.0.xxx* connected to a *Bd SqlServer 2008R2*, I installed Sap *Crystal report runtime framework x64* on my computer to show the reports and printing. All runs well on my computer where I developed the application. I created the executable with *advanced installer* adding two versions of the framework from *SAP Crystal Report x32,x64* for the futur deployments. After installation on an other computer, when I try to do a report that produces the message

> Failed to open the connection.
>
> Details: Database Vendor Code: 17
>
> Failed to open the connection.
>
> Orders.BOL.TaskDetail {393C9017-0ED1-4E1E-8824-E222F4B9D14C}.rpt
>
> Details: Database Vendor Code: 17"

I cannot understand the problem, do you also have that problem and how you solved it ?

Thank you

Here my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Service.ServeurService.IsServeurOn()){
        try
        {
            Facture cryRpt = new Facture();               
            DataSet ds = ctv.ListerVente(codevent);
            cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds);             
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("        Serveur Indisponible    !!!");
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this site is English speaking. Also please be careful when selecting tags, so you don't select the C language tag by mistake, when you meant to select the C# language tag.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  There are no try/catch blocks in C, please [edit] your post to include the correct language tag and remove the C tag.  Please also translate your post to english.

Comment: I translated your question(hopping without fault) , please next time write in English. Did you looked at the other question speaking about that problem : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Database+Vendor+Code+17 ?

Comment: @bruno Please, do not translate questions. We should close them as not suitable for this site. You have no way of knowing if OP knows any English.

Comment: excuse me all of you, i am a newer on stackoverflow, sorry to all of you

Comment: @Dharman it seems you see the glass half empty, while I see it half full, 
so i choose to be optimism ^^

Comment: I checked and tried the different links that you suggested, so far nothing works on my side. the problem is that I can't understand how it could be possible, because there are two reports in my project, one works correctly and the other gives me this message while I have taken the time to check the two reports to see what is the difference between them. I even try to make a copy of the one that works in order to be sure that they have the same characteristics, the same configuration parameters.@bruno